# item expected to be list or string but got 0 netlogo?

Tags: netlogo

Lately my netlogo program behaves strangely. When I run my simulation it gives error "item expected to be list or string but got 0". Normally when this type of error comes, it highlights the line that causing this problem. But in my program this error just pop up but does not highlight any line. I am not sure how to debug which line is causing problem as i have many modules and i used many times "item command" in my program. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I don't know why the line of code, which induces the error doesn't get highlighted. One way to find the location in the code, where the error occures is, to carefully read the error message. Eventually you could post the complete error message. Mostly it states where (in which procedure and in which context) the error occured. However, you could also add `print` statements (e.g. printing the name of the current procedure and turtle number) to your code at those sections where you use the `item` command. Then you should be able to identify the code segment, which causes the problem.

Comment: @Tyr In the error message it does not show which procedure and in which context it is causing the problem. Normally it tells which procedure is causing problem but not in my code.

Comment: This shouldn't happen; there must be a bug in NetLogo itself. Are you able to share the `.nlogo` file? If so, can you post a link to it? If you're only comfortable sharing it privately, you could mail it to bugs@ccl.northwestern.edu.

Comment: Also, in the error dialog that pops up, there should be a "Show internal details" checkbox. Can you check that, and post the complete text that it shows? There might be some clues there.

Comment: @SethTisue  internal details show this message

Comment: ITEM expected input to be a string or list but got the number 0 instead.
error while coalition-group 27818 running ITEM
  called by (command task from: procedure COALITIONDEFICITSUM)
  called by procedure COALITIONDEFICITSUM
  called by procedure NEWCOALITION1
  called by procedure GO
  called by Button 'go'

org.nlogo.nvm.ArgumentTypeException: ITEM expected input to be a string or list but got the number 0 instead.
 at org.nlogo.nvm.EngineException.fillInStackTrace(EngineException.java:81)
 at org.nlogo.nvm.CommandTask.perform(Task.scala:87)
 at org.nlogo.prim.etc._foreach.perform(_foreach.

Comment: You can use gist.github.com or pastebin.com or a similar service to share a link to the complete internal details, which will be much too long to fit in an SO comment.

Answer (score -1):

From [the documentation](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#insert-item) we have this snippet below showing the proper syntax.

```
insert-item index list value
```

Make sure that the `list` value is a **string** or a **list** *before* the use of this in the code.

The line is not highlighted because it (where is is established that `list` is a string or a list) is missing in the code.

An example of correct use would be

```
mylist []
set mylist insert-item 0 mylist "example"
print mylist
```

or

```
mystring "string"
set mystring insert-item 0 mystring "example"
print mystring
```

If mystring or mylist is not previously defined, they will be set to zero.

Comment: if you read the question (and comments) carefully, you will see that the line generating the error is not being marked by the debugger. Therefore your very general advice can't be followed because it is not clear what list needs to be defined properly. OP is asking for advice about how to identify where the problem occurs. Also, this question is almost four years old, adding an answer moves the question up to the top of the `new` list, wasting the time of people who don't notice the age of the question.

Comment: @JenB Sorry about that, but it does seem that issues for this language are far in between, and I think that there is a reason for the error not to show up and I have added that to my answer.